How do you disable doctests in a cargo workspace?
Basically I run cargo test in a workspace and after all the unit tests have run, cargo test starts looking for doctests in every executable.  We don't use these and it takes time to do nothing.
How do I disable this?


From the Cargo docs:

Doc tests for libraries may be disabled by setting doctest = false for the library in the manifest.

This would look something like this:
[package]
name = "my_package"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Joe <joe@example.com>"]

[lib]
doctest = false

I'm not aware of a way to set this at the workplace level - you will likely need to add this to each crate individually.
